# Is there supposed to be a difference between $x^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ ? (Wolfram Alpha shows different results)

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, graphing-functions, radicals, wolfram-alpha

Compare these two functions:
[plot $\sqrt[3]{x}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%E2%88%9Bx)
and
[plot $x^{1/3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E(1%2F3))

I understand how roots are ambiguous, and Wolfram Alpha apparently takes the principle root with the $x^{1/3}$ case and the real root with $\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Is there any reason why the different approach? In the "input interpretation" it displays both as $\sqrt[3]{x}$ and aren't they in fact supposed to mean the same? Isn't $\sqrt[x]{y}$ **defined** as $y^{1/x}$ ?

Comment: I feel it as an example of the necessity of a standard of notation in maths, much like as IUPAC in Chemistry and Physics.

Answer (score 1):

It is taking $\sqrt[3]x$ as the inverse of $x^3$, while $x^{\frac13}$ is define through exponential (aproximating the values with Taylor maybe) for the graph

Answer (score 0):

As far as Wolfram Alpha  is concerned, $x^{\frac13}$ is the [principal cube root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root#Complex_numbers) of $x$. Since that's not a real number when $x<0$, you can't see it in the graph.